# How does array.splice work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

What is really happening in the background. I am a PHP developer and

> unset($arr[5]);

will do the trick in PHP and I would like to know how it works in JavaScript.

Comment: from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) : _The splice() method changes the content of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements._

Comment: How does it remove existing elements?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the JavaScript [specification ECMA 262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.splice) to get the algorithm all browsers have to implement.

In terms of actual code, `Array.prototype.splice` is implemented natively by the browsers engines and it surely varies between them. One example is the [implementation made in the Chakra engine](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/blob/4471e2600c9936e7bf481afd542e8369ddbb2e74/lib/Runtime/Library/JavascriptArray.cpp#L6437) (used by Microsoft Edge). It's written in C++ and it's actually a lot of code.